# Creating types as wrapper for primitive types

Tags: java, typechecking

Quite often we have projects with a lot of entity types (Hibernate/JPA, ...). The entity types have a primitive type like an int, long or string for an ID. We have DAOs and Services that take and return this primitives.

```
long doSomething(long blubId, long blabId, long fooId, long barId, ...)
```

As you can see, it can be very confusing. I'd like to take advantage from the static type checking and have types for it.

```
long doSomething(BlubId blubId, BlabId blabId, FooId fooId, BarId barId, ...)
```

But this seems to be inefficient. Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Note, handling with primitives is sometimes required in the JEE context (JSF backed beans, persistency, ...)

Comment: "But this seems inefficient" - in the situation where you're making a database call, just how significant do you expect that inefficiency to be?

Comment: There's no special way to do this in Java. You would just create a normal class BlubId with a `long` field, a getter, and probably an equals/hash/toString. It would work like any other class. (Other languages have special ways of handling this, but not Java.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It can be inefficient in terms of memory. Imagine a collection of many complex objects. The complex objects in turn, have blubId, blabId, ... as members. It's a low cost in terms of memory to have the IDs as primitive instead of an object (wrapper) which allocates memory on the heap with at least BLOCKSIZE (often = 512b). Also don't forget GC, ...

Comment: In C/C++ one does: typedef unsigned long BlubId; Problem solved.

Comment: @kalamar: Sure, there's be a lot of small objects around, possibly for a very short time. The GC is good at handling that. I'd expect your actual *data* (strings etc) to dwarf that anyway though.Have you actually *measured* the ineffiency, with concrete targets? And sure, there are ways of doing it in C++ - but those approaches don't work in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a prime candidate for the builder pattern where you have a `DoSomethingOptions` class with a `DoSomethingOptionsBuilder` which creates the options explicitly via named methods to avoid confusion of parameter order.

To be honest, I don't see your initial approach being terribly inefficient, but that really depends on how often your `doSomething` method is being called and how long the actual logic of the method takes. Obviously using wrappers to primitives will take more space and a marginal amount of time, but it's nearly inconsequential compared to any real computation.

Comment: A builder object would have the same issue as the original method. Each of the builder methods would use a `long`, so you could still end up using the wrong table ID

Comment: I think a combination of wrapped primitives and the builder pattern would be a smart solution... as long as the call to `doSomething` takes enough time to ignore the cost of creating a few objects.

Comment: The benefit you get from the builder method is that you have an explicit line saying `builder.withBlubId(123).withOtherSpecificId(234)` which gives you named parameters, so it's harder to get the order messed up. It sounds like that's the issue that he's trying to avoid in the first place. How do you see someone mistakenly using the wrong tableId with this paradigm?

Comment: That would still only help if the variable names are obvious. Imagine instead the call looked like this `builder.withBlubId(foo).withOtherSpecificId(bar)`. It's still not obvious at a glance that `foo` is actually a `BlubId` or if you mixed it up with `bar`

Comment: Correct, but poor naming for variables and lack of transparency for parameters of identical types are two different issues. The latter can be solved with the builder pattern and the former can be solved with naming your variables something other than `foo` and `bar` which may seem reasonable in a contrived example but in practice I find it suspect that they would be naming their variables as such.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you may be interested into looking already written Java wrapper classes [Java Primitive Wrapper class](http://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java)

Comment: Nope, the point is that `BlubId` and `BlabId` are both wrappers for `long`, but for different tables. I don't see how `Long` would help with that.